# Fluid children inside parent

Tags: html, css

I have a div which has 5 children. I want that the space of the parent to be devided equaly for the 5 children. So if parent has a width of 1000px each children with have a width of 200px. I have tried setting `width: 20%; height: 20%;` for the children but the problem is that the parent will have no defined height. The parent height will be determined by the children height. So if the screen is resized each children with take up `1/5 of width of the parent` and the height of the child will also be equal its width. So parent width will be 100% of the screen and the parent height will be equal to child height. I have tried media queries but I think it is a more simple way of doing this since I'm only changing the width and the height, I'm not changing the overall design of the page.

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>

<style>
    #parent {width: 100%}
    .child {}
</style>
```

Comment: flexbox is the answer here.

Comment: that doesn't make any sense. the outer div is referring to the height of the inner divs to determine it's own height, so the inner divs cannot refer to the outer div for their height.

Comment: Yes I know. Thats the problem

Comment: @rexhin no, your question doesn't make sense. you say you want the parent to determine the height of the child, then you say you want the opposite, so which is it? and what is supposed to determine the height of the other?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you want flexible elements that retain their aspect ratio. You can and should use flexbox because it's awesome but if not you can do it like this:

```
.child {
    position: relative;
    width: 20%;     
}
.child:before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 100%; /* 1:1 ratio */
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/srhogfh8/

Or as seen here: http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html

(There is a little red space which is the parent container because of display: inline-block. You can get rid of the spaces and any need for margin-left: -4px by having no spaces in the html for the list. But your html will look messy.)

Answer (score 0):

```
.child {width:20%;}
```

Will force the children to be 1/5 of whatever the parent width is.

Answer (score 0):

```
height: 20vh;
```

try this, it is 20% of viewport height;
More here: http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/WD-css3-values-20060919/

Sorry I mean

```
width: 20vw;
```

It is 20% of viewport width;

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correct you simply need to set the children's `width:20%;`

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#parent {width: 100%;}
.child { width:20%; float:left;}
```

As you can see in the fiddle below the children determines the parent's height and children responds to the parent's width (fluid).

See working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ggChris/ff4ukdge/1/

Answer (score 0):

Basic Example of Flexbox - without attributes for cross browser support :

```html
<div style = 'display:flex'> 
    <div style = 'flex:1;'><div>
    <div style = 'flex:1;'><div>
    <div style = 'flex:1;'><div>
    <div style = 'flex:1;'><div>
    <div style = 'flex:1;'><div>
</div>
```

Flex:1 says that each of them shall be equal in size. 5 boxes, 100%/5 = 20%.

Use `flex-wrap:row` or `flex-wrap:column` depending on how you want them set up, and visit https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ to learn about flexboxes

For Cross Browser Support 
Modern Chrome, Safari, Firefox and IE11+
I use the following classes 
And the way it would be set up in this example is

```css
.flexme{
        display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
        display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
        display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
        display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
        display: flex;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
        }
    .flexrow { 
            -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
            flex-flow: row wrap;
        }   
    .flexrownowrap { 
            -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
            flex-flow: column nowrap;
        }    
    .flexcol { 
            -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
            flex-flow: column wrap;
        } `
```

```html
<div class = 'flexme flexcol'>
  <!-- flexcol assuming you want them in columns -->
  <div class = 'flex1'><div>
  <div class = 'flex1'><div>
  <div class = 'flex1'><div>
  <div class = 'flex1'><div>
  <div class = 'flex1'><div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey this doesn't show anything when I run.

Comment: Not at computer right now to edit - but try it in your file. Just give the parent div a height and add some background colors to make sure you can see it.

Comment: That is the problem. the parent div will be equal to child height.

Comment: so if the parent has a width of 1000px the child width will be 200px its height will be 200px also and by this the parent height will be also 200px